# Google invisible Recaptcha token and validation endpoints are hosted in different domains

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

We are using the Google invisible Recaptcha to detect genuine logins to our application. The "recaptcha.js" hits the `https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/userverify` endpoint which gives the Recaptcha token.
The API to verify the user's response is `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`

Questions:

1. Can there be a possibility that the endpoint `https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/userverify` (used by the Recaptcha JS script) is available and this endpoint `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` is down or vice versa?
2. Why are the user verification endpoint and the token verification endpoints hosted in different domains?
3. How do we determine the availability of the recaptcha validation service?